# Mern, Deleting comments issue

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, redux, mern

I can not delete comments inside of a single post. I do not know what causes this but apparently I was getting a 404 Error, I do not know why the post was not found, to be honest. I would love to get help and see what is causing this and why I am getting this Error, and why I am not able to delete a comment from a post. Below I will post some of my back ends as well as my front end code, but I will also make sure to link to my Github down below. I have been struggling with this for almost 3 days, I am not seeing what exactly causes the error and I would love some help. 
Another thing to mention is that I am pretty new into MERN, so please also have a look at my Github code, and suggest changes or things I could do better, that would mean a lot to me honestly.
*Below will be some code and a link to my Github Repo for this specific project*

https://github.com/tigerabrodi/ELance

Route for Deleting a Comment from a post

```js
// @route    DELETE api/posts/comment/:commentId 
// @desc     Delete comment
// @access   Private
router.delete("/comment/:commentId", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const comment = await Comment.findById(req.params.commentId);

    if (!comment) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Comment do not exist" });
    }

    if (comment.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
      return res.status(401).json({ msg: "User not authorized" });
    }

    await comment.remove();

    res.json({msg: "Comment Removed"})
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Post.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import PostItem from '../posts/PostItem';
import CommentForm from '../post/CommentForm';
import CommentItem from '../post/CommentItem';
import { getPost } from '../../redux/post/post.actions';
import {getSinglePostComments} from "../../redux/comment/comment.actions"

const Post = ({ getPost, getSinglePostComments, post: { post, loading }, comment, match }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getPost(match.params.id);
    getSinglePostComments(match.params.id)
  }, [comment.comments]);

  return loading || comment.loading || post === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <Fragment>
      <Link to='/posts' className='btn btn-info m-3'>
        Back To Posts
      </Link>
      <PostItem post={post} showActions={false} />
      <CommentForm postId={post._id} />
      <div className='comments'>
        {comment.comments.map(comment => (
          <CommentItem key={comment._id} comment={comment} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post,
  comment: state.comment
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPost, getSinglePostComments }
)(Post);
```

CommentItem.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import {deleteComment} from '../../redux/comment/comment.actions';
import defaultUserImage from "../../assets/default-user-icon.jpg"

const CommentItem = ({
  comment: { _id, text, user, date },
  auth,
  deleteComment
}) => (

    <div class="card m-5 bg-warning">
  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <Link to={`/profile/${user._id}`}>
            <img className='card-img rounded-circle pl-2' src={user.avatar ? user.avatar : defaultUserImage} alt='' />
            </Link>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">{user.name}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{text}</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Posted on <Moment format='YYYY/MM/DD'>{date}</Moment>
</small></p>
      {!auth.loading && user._id === auth.user._id && (
        <button
          onClick={() => deleteComment(_id)}
          type='button'
          className='btn btn-danger float-right mb-4'
        >
          <i className='fas fa-times' />
        </button>
      )}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { deleteComment }
)(CommentItem);
```

CommentForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addComment } from '../../redux/comment/comment.actions';

const CommentForm = ({ postId, addComment }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className='container'>
        <div className="row">
        <div className="col text-center">
         <div>
        <h4>Leave a Comment</h4>
      </div>
      <form
        className='form my-1 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center'
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          addComment(postId, { text });
          setText('');
        }}
      >
        <textarea
          name='text'
          className="form-control bg-info text-light"
          placeholder='Comment the post'
          value={text}
          onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <input type='submit' className='btn btn-outline-info ml-3' value='Submit' />
      </form>
    </div>
        </div>
        </div>

  );
};

export default connect(
  null,
  { addComment }
)(CommentForm);
```

comment.actions.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import {setAlert} from "../alert/alert.actions"
import {CommentActionTypes} from "./comment.types"


// Get Comments For a Single Post
export const getSinglePostComments = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/posts/comments/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: CommentActionTypes.GET_SINGLE_POST_COMMENTS,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: CommentActionTypes.COMMENT_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};



  // Add Comment
  export const addComment = (postId, formData) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };

    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`/api/posts/comment/${postId}`, formData, config);

        dispatch({
          type: CommentActionTypes.ADD_COMMENT,
          payload: res.data
        });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
          type: CommentActionTypes.COMMENT_ERROR,
          payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
        });
      }
  }

 // Delete comment
export const deleteComment = (commentId) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    await axios.delete(`api/posts/comment/${commentId}`);

    dispatch({
      type: CommentActionTypes.DELETE_COMMENT,
      payload: commentId
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Comment Removed', 'success'));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: CommentActionTypes.COMMENT_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

comment.reducer.js

```
import {CommentActionTypes} from "./comment.types";



const initialState = {
    comments: [],
    loading: true,
    error: {}
}

const commentReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const {payload, type} = action;
    switch (type) {
            case CommentActionTypes.GET_SINGLE_POST_COMMENTS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    comments: payload,
                    loading: false
                }
            case CommentActionTypes.ADD_COMMENT:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    comments: [payload, ...state.comments],
                    loading: false
                }
            case CommentActionTypes.DELETE_COMMENT:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    comments: state.comments.filter(comment => comment._id !== payload),
                    loading: false
                }
            case CommentActionTypes.COMMENT_ERROR:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    error: payload,
                    loading: false
                }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default commentReducer
```

comment.types.js

```
export const CommentActionTypes = {
    DELETE_COMMENT: "DELETE_COMMENT",
    ADD_COMMENT: "ADD_COMMENT",
    COMMENT_ERROR: "COMMENT_ERROR",
    GET_SINGLE_POST_COMMENTS: "GET_SINGLE_POST_COMMENTS"
}
```

Comment: While I could debug your code for you, I don't think you'll learn the process of debugging by not doing it yourself. So, instead, I'll give you some tips: Install `morgan` on your backend (it's a logging framework that logs requests to your API to the console), then break down each step: 1.) Does the redux action get called AND with the right `id`? 2.) Does the API call reach the backend (thats where morgan comes in handy). 3.) Does the request reach the correct controller? 4.) Does the controller receive the `id` and does it match a `comment` record that already exists?

Comment: Somewhere, in one of those steps, will be your problem. Remember, you can console.log each of the steps to make sure they're executing normally and/or seeing if they're throwing errors. To make things even easier, you can use postman  (https://www.getpostman.com/) to send requests directly to the API and you can use MongoDB Compass to view current Mongo databases and documents: https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass. If you're still stuck, let me know and I'll help. But, I'd encourage you to try the above first.

Comment: Btw I did try debugging, second thing, it works with postman, you are able to delete a comment, i tried it yesterday. Third thing, It is a Front End problem I believe, cause I get a 404 saying "Not Found", While I did set up a 404 error if no comments exist saying: Comment does not exist. For that reason honestly i dont know what else to do, front end seems fine and back end too....

Comment: I would still love if you could debug it, i strugglewd with this for almost 2-3 days now, would be great to get it done today at least since i do not have any school. There for i even beg you to debug it.

Comment: I will not continue debugging, I did set up morgan and checked the back end again, the back end is working fine, im now gonna check if the front end part does it job by going into the app.

Comment: Tbh I even beg you to debug it, I can not see what is wrong here, have tried everything, the back end part works fine tested with postman, but still in redux devtools, it gives me the comment error saying a 404 and Not Found. I honestly do not know what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comment.actions.js deleteComment method, you need to add a slash to the beginning of the delete url:

```js
    await axios.delete(`/api/posts/comment/${commentId}`);
```

Comment: Holy fuck, you saved my day, I do not know you but one thing is for sure, may god bless you dude. This was a small typo error, hahaha thanks man!

Comment: I have another 10h to code on new feautures instead of crying and debugging